# Bad Request Error (400) or Not Found Error (404) during extracting request parameters in jax-rs

Tags: jax-rs

In docs.oracle ( https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs002.htm ) about Extracting Request Parameters we have:

> If the URI path template variable cannot be cast to the specified type, the JAX-RS runtime returns an HTTP 400 (“Bad Request”) error to the client. 
>   If the @PathParam annotation cannot be cast to the specified type, the JAX-RS runtime returns an HTTP 404 (“Not Found”) error to the client.

Could someone explain the difference, maybe give an example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but if you define method with path param and it fails on cast string to custom type, jax-rs (in my case jersey servlet) returns 404 error, and it's very strange and unexpected.

```java
package com.example.jaxrs.api;
...
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}/info")
    public Response info(@PathParam UUID id) { ... }
```

`curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/123/info` --> `HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found`

This behavior can be changed. Just create simple ExceptionMapper, catch the ParamException, and return correct "400 Bad Request" response.

```java
package com.example.jaxrs.errors;

@Provider
public class PathParamExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ParamException> {
  @Override
  public Response toResponse(ParamException exception) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
  }
}
```

Do not forgot annotation @Provider and add the package with error handler to servlet init param.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.jaxrs.api;com.example.jaxrs.errors</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```